# angular how to check is the model is changed or not

Tags: angular

I am using angular 4 and i want check that 
is any value is changed by user or not?  In my page there are more than 100 control(textbox ,dropdown and editable grid)

I need to check only if any value is changed or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can subscribe to the formControl's [valuesChanged property](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges).

```
yourFormControl.valuesChanged.subscribe( value => {
   console.log(value); //will output the new value from yourFormControl
});
```

Note that the form itself has this property.

```
this.yourForm = this.formBuilder.group( /* etc... */)
this.yourForm.valuesChanged.subscribe( form => {
   console.log(form); //will output the new value from the entire form, every time one of its child is changed
});
```

Comment: Thanks Christian for response.  In which event i can call below part                           this.yourForm = this.formBuilder.group( /* etc... */)
this.yourForm.valuesChanged.subscribe( form => {
   console.log(form); //will output the new value from the entire form, every time one of its child is changed
});

Comment: No need to call this in an event. After the form is created, you can subscribe to this 'valueChanges' and then, everytime a value is changed, it will be emited. Take a look here with a full example https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-valuechanges/